# Which programming language has complete implementation API of Gnome 3 (binding)?

Tags: javascript, python, linux, vala, gnome-3

As far as i know there are several programming language to develop program for Gnome 3 (Python, JavaScript, Vala, C, C++).

I was wondering which language has complete implementation API of Gnome 3 binding and also which of them support complete application development tools life-cycle (UI designer, Test Framework, IDE,...)?

I am going to use JavaScript is it a good choose with above concerns?

Comment: "Fastest" is fastest you can develop and "Best" is some definition defined elsewhere. Please avoid terms like "fastest" and "best" in titles (unless they *really are* relevant). SO is not a good place to "conduct a poll" or gather cursory research information.

Comment: My question is only about complete binding and developments tools.

Comment: It is not about "complete". It is about being "complete enough" (i.e. "usable and sufficient for you") within other restrictions (preferences/skills/functional requirements). There are a number of different languages with a number of different goals/ideologies/approachs with a number of different bindings and a number of different editors/IDEs and a number of different testing frameworks for a number of different kinds of tests. That is, this question is as [ill]suited for SO as "Which programming language is best for Web Development?"

Comment: For whom closed this post: the question was perfectly fine. It's not a "what language is better than another". The question is asking for experience about what's the language complete in an domain specific environment, which is very legit given that many changes have happend to the gnome world with GI. This is not a question about feelings, it's a very practical question and makes a lot of sense. Please consider reopening the question. Also how do I vote for reopening this question?

Comment: There is a link (called reopen) between question text and comments. see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close

Answer (score 2):

I'd say Vala has the most complete bindings, plus you can easily modify the existing bindings for your own project if they don't work properly, which makes it a robust choice compared to using plain gobject introspection in other languages. But I'm biased :)

Vala however has less development tools.

Comment: How about unit and integration test utilities?

Comment: Vala compiles straight to GObject/C. If there is a testing framework in GObject/C, you can have it. You can use the glib testing. Also there are a couple of projects and examples here: https://live.gnome.org/Vala/Documentation . In other words, your last question is more appropriate for google rather than stackoverflow.